# Vim syntax highlighting for ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Ruby 1.9 has a few new syntax elements, such as the `{key: value}` hash literal syntax. Has anyone written or seen an updated `syntax/ruby.vim` highlighting file that will highlight `key:` just like it highlights `:key` in `{:key => value}`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the latest version from github:

http://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/syntax/ruby.vim

It was updated in December of 2009, and seems to do the right thing with the new hash literals.

Comment: perfect, thanks. not quite sure why I hadn't tried this - but I have now!

Comment: for the record, you don't have to use the whole `vim-ruby` plugin -- you can simply save the file linked above to `~/.vim/syntax/ruby.vim` (`mkdir ~/.vim/syntax` if necessary)

Comment: Execute `wget https://raw.github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/master/syntax/ruby.vim` while in `~/.vim/syntax` to download only this file from repo

Answer (score 0):

Thoughtbot's dot files might be another good place to start:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles