# Fortran Namelist syntax highlighing in Vim?

Tags: fortran, vim-syntax-highlighting

The fortran namelist syntax is defined in a few places, like on the [Intel website](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-00A22D3B-39F4-46A6-8A6F-BF484EFE19CB.htm) and at http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/f90model/slides/namelist.html. I'm not sure if these are complete or even consistent, but *some* syntax highlighting would be better than none. Is there any such syntax highlighter?

Comment: If this should be closed, then what about these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564627/vim-syntax-highlighting-for-ruby-1-9, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558884/razor-cshtml-syntax-highlighting-for-vim

Comment: You really should emphasize you care about ViM and do not ask for any random tool. The word `vi` or `vim` does not appear in your question at all. The question you referenced is written in a much clearer way.

Comment: @VladimirF: Whoa... I can't believe I missed that. I swear I put it in there somewhere, maybe I edited it out. Thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to `~/.vimrc` allowed vim to recognise namelist files as fortran files, and the syntax highlighting that is applied is adequate:

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.nml set filetype=fortran
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.namelist set filetype=fortran
endif
```